# Case sensitivity in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, case-sensitive

As Dart is case sensitive, therefore I was *expecting* all of Flutter to be case sensitive. Found out that importing packages is quite often *non case sensitive*.

Can anyone confirm and link to official documentation? I could not find definite answer on my own. Any other Flutter *behaviors* that are not case sensitive to be aware of? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems it's related to the operating system running the program

Check out the comment on [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9539#issuecomment-296777629)

It quotes:

> Windows doesn't care if a file is named Test.dart or test.dart. For Windows (and Dart on Windows), it's the same. However, when we copy the file over to Android, it is important that we distinguish between the two. For Android (and Dart on Android) Test.dart and test.dart are not the same!

However it seems to be fixed with [this PR](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/9571)

Official dart style guide says to name files with `lowercase_with_underscores`, find the doc [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style#do-name-libraries-and-source-files-using-lowercase_with_underscores). It's always better to follow the official style guides for naming, be it files, functions or classes.

Checkout official style guide [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style#do-name-libraries-and-source-files-using-lowercasewithunderscores).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you - the github link is spot on and official. Any other such non case sensitive behavior you know of?